# Problema con la interfaz de diseño Android studio

Tags: android-studio

No me aparece la paleta de objetos para el diseño, ni las pestañas para mostras text o diseño, nada de diseño, estoy empezando con Android pero comencé con el pie izquierdo ya que no me funciona ayuda por favor

Comment: Podrías mostrar una imagen de lo que te aparece?

Comment: Muestra algo de codigo y si puedes alguna imagen del problema generado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte